# JSDoc type cast for `window`?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm curious what type definition I should use for a window being passed into a function. Normally I use HTMLElement, but I don't think the window is an HTMLElement

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof(window)` returns `object`. If you are looking to define the interface type it inherits from:

> The window object implements the Window interface, which in turn
>   inherits from the AbstractView interface.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: yea not typeof, just the type according to JSDoc, which would be `/** @type {Window} */` then, thanks